# always getting RESULT_CANCELL onActivityResult while

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, startactivityforresult

In my project I have activity A that has a list. I set onClickListener in list adaptor (onBindViewHolder) that by clicking on every items, activity B being started (startActivityforResult).then in Activity B I setResult(RESULT_OK)
but in Activity A always getting RESULT_CANCELL.

here is my adaptor code :

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,TicketActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ticketID",tickets.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("ticketStatus",tickets.get(position).getStatus());
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent,NEW_TICKET_MESSAGE_CODE);
        }
    });
```

here is Activity B when I setResult as OK.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(hasNewMessage) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }else{
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
    finish();

}
```

I'm sure that hasNewMessage returns true. 
and here is Activity B where I check for result :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == NEW_TICKET_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            recreate();
        }

    } if (requestCode == NEW_TICKET_MESSAGE_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            recreate();
        }
    }
}
```

But request with code NEW_TICKET_MESSAGE_CODE always gets RESULT_CANCEL
why?!

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent();                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();` I noticed you have not created an intent, then pass back using `setResult`

Comment: @Eenvincible I did it, but my problem was not resolved

Comment: The intent is for optional extra data, it isn’t required, I think it could be the “finish” call you’re making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `super.onBackPressed();` line

your method must like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(hasNewMessage) {
         setResult(RESULT_OK);
         finish();
    }else{
         setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
         finish();
    }

}
```